# Magento 2 Insert Template into cms page

Tags: magento2, template, cms

I created a template (phtml) and placed it into my theme folder. I then went to a cms block and placed this

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Magento_Theme::footer-social.phtml"}}
```

Nothing renders. I've read other posts in regard to this and they all seem to be similar.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like template path is incorrect.

In your example Magento will search your template at path:

```
app/code/Magento/Theme/view/frontend/templates/footer-social.phtml
```

Next syntax works for me, inserted directly into `Content > Pages > Home Page > Content` (WYSIWYG hidden)

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Yaronish_Cms::home.phtml"}}
```

[image]

File path
    app/code/Yaronish/Cms/view/frontend/templates/home.phtml

File Content

```
<div>My Home Template</div>
<?php
    echo microtime(true);
?>
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: I moved my file there. I was in design and not the code folder. It didn't change anything. Do I need to run a deployment script?

Comment: You have to clean Page Cache

Comment: I did. Still no change.  Is that the appropriate class to use?

Comment: Want to help you, but I need additional information: Magento version, template path, template content, cms block content. Thanks.